# Select top n records based on sum of 2 columns for each day

Tags: mysql

I have a table with sample data as follows:

```
Date                | hostname   |bytesIn|bytesOut|
2018/02/26 11:57:37 | abc.com    | 100   | 500
2018/02/26 11:57:37 | abc.com    | 50    | 500
2018/02/25 11:57:37 | xyz.com    | 100   | 300
2018/02/25 11:57:37 | abc.com    | 100   | 500
2018/02/25 11:57:37 | def.com    | 200   | 500
```

I want to select top n record based on total bytes(bytesIn+bytesOut) for each day. I need to calculate sum of the bytesIn and bytesOut columns and format the Date column(omit hh:mm:ss part) to get daily sum of totalbytes for a specific hostname. then I need to get top n hostnames for each day based on total bytes. e.g, I need to get which hostnames consumes the bandwith most on a daily basis.

I saw similar questions but couldn't apply the answers to my questions. 
How can I get these records?

expected output should be like this (top 2 hostnames according to bandwith let's say):

```
2018/02/26 | abc.com | 600
2018/02/26 | xyz.com | 550
2018/02/25 | def.com | 750
2018/02/25 | qwe.com | 300
2018/02/24 | asd.com | 550
2018/02/24 | sdf.com | 520
```

Comment: can you write the expected output with the example data ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are asking multiple questions. This seems to be an assignment to me. Try to do it first.

Comment: not an assignment, I'm trying to create a report on a siem. added expected ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will be helpful to you,

```
select hostname, Dates, totalBytes
from  
    ( select @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
join  
    ( select @n := if( Dates != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
             @prev := Dates,
             hostname, Dates, totalBytes
      from ( select hostname,DATE_FORMAT(dates, '%Y/%m/%d') as Dates,
                    (sum(bytesIn) + sum(bytesOut)) totalBytes
             from your_table
             group by hostname,dates
             order by  Dates desc, totalBytes desc
           ) T1
     ) T2       
where n <= 2
```

`n` specify the number of record per day.

[Click here for SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2779e/3)

Comment: it gives all records. I need to get top n records for each day.

Comment: give n as limit. if n = 1 then set limit 1 in query . In the above query I have given n as 5

Comment: if limit is 1, it shows just one record. it should show 1 record for each day. that's where I got stuck.

Comment: it worked perfectly. I'm not very familiar with this method. what is it?(i want to learn)

Comment: @MehmetErgene have you heard about ROW_NUMBER () 
OVER ([PARTITION in SQL actually mysql do not support this that is why i  have done this using above query. Better you to first of all have a look on  ROW_NUMBER () 
OVER ([PARTITION in SQL.if it is working for you please accept it as your answer

Comment: for more details you please visit the site http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max